# How to upload multiple images in Django using Dropzone and saving path dynamically ?

Tags: django, django-models, dropzone.js, django-registration, django-uploads

I am working on a Django project where users should be able to upload images using [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration) At the moment user images would be saved under mypp/images folder
However I would like to save the path of uploaded images dynamically.
E.g. /images//image1.jpg
Btw I am using [django-registraion-redux](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package (v 1.1) to handle my user registration & login.
These are my codes:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

get_user_image_folder(instance, filename):
return "%s/%s" % (instance.user.user.username, filename)

class Picture(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_user_image_folder,)
```

**foms.py**

```
class PictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Picture
    fields = ('image',)
```

**views.py**

```
def upload_picture(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PictureForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        picture = form.save()
else:
    form = PictureForm()
return render(request, "upload_picture.html", locals())
```

**Template**

```
  <body>
    <form action="{% url 'upload_picture' %}" class="dropzone" id="myDropzone" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="fallback">
            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="{% static 'dropzone/dropzone.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Dropzone.options.myDropzone ={
            paramName: "image", // name of input
            autoProcessQueue : true,
            parallelUploads: 1,

            init :  function (){
                this.on( "success", function( file, responseText){
                    // event launched at the end of uploading images queued
                    console.log( responseText );
                });
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [url(r'^upload-picture/', 'myapp.views.upload_picture', name='upload_picture'),]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/mhsha/Desktop/board'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Right now when I try to upload an image I get the error :
AttributeError at /upload-picture/ 'Picture' object has no attribute 'user'
any suggestion would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Models.py:**

You have: instance.user.user.username. There's an extra .user there. It should be something like this:

```
def get_user_image_folder(instance, filename):
return 'images/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.username, filename)

class Picture(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_user_image_folder)
```

This should work.

Comment: omg ty so much Rooz I was stuck in that for a day =_= the problem is resolved now

Answer (score 1):

use
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "/media/")